# ANSI C: How to convert a float value into a short variable

Tags: c

sorry for the simple question, but how can I convert f.e. 29.4 into 0x0DBE and -12 into 0x8350.

```
int ss_bat_temp = 294;    //a temperatur in 0.1 Celsius
fvalue = (float) ss_bat_temp / 10; 
short svalue = (short)(fvalue);
```

But it doesn't work.

The result is 0x001D not 0x0DBE. What is the problem?

Could anybody help me?

Comment: use    'short svalue = (short)(fvalue)'??  I think that is a typo

Comment: Why do you expect `0x0DBE`?

Comment: (short)29.4 = 29 = 0x1D, whats the problem?

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: That sounds about right to me. `294.0 / 10` is `29.4`, casting that to an integer truncates it to `29` which is `0x1d`.

Comment: Your code works fine, it gives the expected result of 0x1d. Why do you expect 0x0DBE ?

Comment: BUT I expect 0x0DBE. This is the right value in HEX for 29.40 degree celsius. Anybody an idea to convert it from 29.40?

Comment: Do you want to get the binary representation of the float value and use that ("the bits") to store it into the short?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry it is not obvious to us how 0x0DBE is the right value for 29.40 you will have to explain it.

Comment: If you want the raw bits there are a couple of ways to do that *type punning*. ***But*** you do know that `float` is a 32-bit data-type? Putting the data from a `float` into a `short` (which is 16 bits on just about all platforms) will mean some truncation, especially when it comes to negative numbers.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you could tell us *why* you want this? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: short encode_dpt9(float fval)
{
    int mant = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    short sign = 0;
    
    if (fval < 0)
        sign = 0x8000;
    mant = (int)(fval * 100.0);
    while (abs(mant) > 2047) {
        mant /= 2;
        exp++;
    }
    return sign | (exp << 11) | (mant & 0x07ff);
}

Comment: it's the solution of your problem or some new information to help you ? in first case post an answer, in second, edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Float is a 8 bytes long and short is 4(I think).When converting from float to short you lose those some information since you have to shrink it down.